# NullPointerException on SimpMessagingTemplate in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket, spring-messaging

I am building an application that will send messages using STOMP over websockets. I want to send messages without a request being made by the client. According to the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-handle-send), I can do this by using convertAndSend.

However when I try and do this, I get a null pointer exception. Please see code below:

```
public class ParseJSON {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    public void getDetails(String json) {

       try {
            Tweet status = sendDetails(TwitterObjectFactory.createStatus(json));
            sentToWebApp(status);

        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 50)
    private void sentToWebApp(Tweet status) {
        System.out.println(status);
        this.template.convertAndSend("/tweet/update", status);
    }
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.myproject.worker.ParseJSON.sentToWebApp(ParseJSON.java:62)
    at org.myproject.worker.ParseJSON.getDetails(ParseJSON.java:51)
    at org.myproject.worker.TwitterClient.run(TwitterClient.java:50)
    at org.myproject.Controllers.TweetController.greeting(TweetController.java:37)
```

Can anybody pour any light onto my situation so I'm able to send a message via websocket without encountering an exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `template` is never assigned.

Comment: @PaulBoddington please check the link in the post, template is never assigned according to the documentation.

Comment: It is assigned in that example. That's what the line `this.template = template;` does.

Comment: I had this problem as well. This answer helped me a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template variable is not properly autowired thats why its giving nullpointerException .

you can check spring configuration to autowire correctly